# How use all upstream changes from a "git stash pop" conflict?

Tags: git

First let me lay out a scenario:

I start working on some code, but I become unsure of some of the changes I have made, while I am sure about others. So, I decide that I want to do one part of what I have in-progress as a single commit, and to do the other part after that is done, possibly with a better idea of how the second part should work, given how the first part was done.

After that, I stage some lines and stash others, then finish the first part and commit it.
I then pop the stash, and run into a conflict that looks something like this:

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
+   Keep this
=======
+   Don't want this
>>>>>>> Stashed changes

+   Keep this
```

(The real example has more changes then this but this hopefully gets the structure across.)

Is there a git command to keep the `Keep this` lines and get rid of the conflict markers and the `Don't want this` lines without editing the file manually? `git checkout --theirs .` keeps the bottom `Keep this` but deletes the top one and keeps the `Don't want this` line. `git checkout --ours .` keeps the top `Keep this`, but deletes all the other lines, including the bottom `Keep this`.

Comment: By the description, if I understood correctly, you will need a manual merge, since you want part of one commit and part of another. Otherwise, git checkout --<theirs/ours> would work

Comment: I'm not sure if it would make a difference, but the way I would describe what I want is to be able to split apart stashed commit into the parts that don't conflict, and those that do, and then throw away the conflicting parts. Given that `git` has to check for these conflicts anyway, I don't see why it would be hard to make a simple command that does what I want here. Whether they actually have, is of course a different story.

Answer (score 2):

#### The best way

Avoid `git stash` entirely.  It's too late for that, but remember it for next time: `git stash` is sometimes handy, but as tools go, is not very good.  Try to use it as little as possible.

#### The second best way, maybe

Given that you already ran `git stash`, turn the stash into a branch, as if you had used the best way.  We'll start with `git reset --hard` to put everything back to the way it was before you attempted to `git stash pop`.

**IMPORTANT:** If you have work you wanted to save, you need to commit it before you attempt the `git stash pop` that messes it up.  But you already ran `git stash pop` and now it's messed up.  You'll have to un-mess it manually now and commit.  That's why it was best to avoid `git stash` entirely back at the start.  I'm assuming that `git reset --hard` is OK here.  I'm also assuming the stash was made *without* `-u` or `-a`.

```
git reset --hard   # !!! SEE IMPORTANT NOTE ABOVE
```

Now that your current (`HEAD`) commit, index, and work-tree all match, we can turn the existing stash into a branch:

```
git stash branch tmp
git status
# run "git commit" and "git add" if / as needed / desired, then
git commit
```

The `git stash branch` command:

- checks out the commit that was active when you ran `git stash`, as a detached HEAD;
- uses `git stash apply --index` to update the index from the `i` commit in the stash (this may or may not do anything); and
- uses the `w` commit in the stash to adjust your work-tree files

so in most cases you are now ready to `git add` and `git commit` to turn what you had stashed, into a real commit.

Now that you have a real commit on a real branch named `tmp`, you can:

```
git checkout branch-where-I-was-working
# now run any Git command, such as:
git cherry-pick -Xours tmp
```

or use any of Git's other various tools.

---

Note: the `git stash` command actually runs `git merge-recursive` the way `git cherry-pick` would, with a forced merge base.  The merge base is the commit that was active at the time you ran `git stash`, i.e., commit `stash^`.  You can manually run `git merge-recursive` yourself.  This is just a single-command method of doing the above `git cherry-pick`.  It's not pretty, but it is short.  Note that there is no documentation for the `git merge-recursive` command and I am working from memory here:

```
git reset --hard   # same as before, with same important caveat
git merge-recursive -Xours stash^ -- HEAD stash
```

#### The single-file way

If the `git reset --hard` is a bad idea—if this would lose work—you can just run a single `git merge-file` on the three inputs to redo the one conflicted merge.<sup>1</sup>  Here, you would want:

```
git checkout-index --stage=all pathname
```

This will print three file names, for the merge base version of the file (from `stash^`), the "ours" version (from `HEAD` / working-tree), and the "theirs" version (from `stash`).  Those three file names are for hidden (dot) files; make a note of them.  You can now run:

```
git merge-file --ours <ours-name> <base-name> <theirs-name>
```

to get the combined changes done as if you had run a `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` with the `-Xours` option.  The resulting file will be in the (still hidden) *`ours-name`* file; if it's the result you wanted, rename it to the right file name and use `git add` to store it into Git's index, in place of the merge conflict.  In any case delete all the remaining temporary files, so as to clean up.

---

<sup>1</sup>There really should be a Git tool to do this.

Comment: I tried making a separate branch as described, on a test repo where I set up an analogous situation.After running `git stash branch tmp`, the partial changes I had already saved in the other commit were staged, and the rest of the stashed commit was in the unstaged changes section, which left me puzzled as to what I was expected to commit. I eventually figured out that I could make a commit that only had the parts I wanted to keep from the stashed commit, which I could then cherry pick as described. Picking those lines was more manual than I had hoped when asking this question,

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response anyway. If there's no way to make the commit I wanted without manually picking lines, then I guess the answer to my question is no.

Comment: Ultimately, the issue here is that you've made yourself extra work from the beginning, and have to untangle it. I should perhaps have gone into more detail about `git stash branch`: it really does restore the index and work-tree independently, so that you *can* make *two* commits out of it all, but in the end, that's all Git has: the committed copies of files, the index copies (from which you can make a commit), and the work-tree copies (from which you can `git add` to copy them into the index, replacing the old ones, and then commit).